# What is ClaimedIdentifier in OpenID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid

I was just reading how can you use OpenID with Asp.Net reading this article:

[Tutorial Link](http://danhounshell.com/blog/adding-openid-to-your-web-site-in-conjunction-with-asp-net-membership/)

I want to know what is Claimed Identifier (what is it's funda) and why is the author using it as username in

```
Membership.CreateUser()
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [OpenID specification](http://openid.net/developers/specs/):

> **[2. Terminology](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html#anchor2)**
>   **Claimed Identifier:**
>   An Identifier that the End User says they own, though that has not yet been verified by the Consumer.
>   **Verified Identifier:**
>   An Identifier that the End User has proven to a Consumer that they own.

So the difference is, that a claimed identifier isn't verified yet and the author probably just didn't want to use real/verified credentials for the tutorial.

Hope that helps!